# How can I properly align header with centered div element?

Tags: html, css

I want the header to align at the top-left-corner of the centered div element. The only way I can think of doing this is setting `position` to `relative` and using `top` with a value of 20%. The problem with this is that it causes the header to stretch the page further to the right as can be see in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyLkdxrs/1/).

```css
body {
  font-family: Europa;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

h4 {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #6441a5;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h4>header</h4>
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply give your header block the same width as your box.

```css
body {
  font-family: Europa;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width:500px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

h4 {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #6441a5;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h4>header</h4>
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a .centered wrapping div you can more easily obtain your desired results w/ keeping the elements fluid if wanted.

```
<div class="centered">
  <h4>header</h4>
  <div class="speech-bubble"></div> 
</div>

<style>
h4 {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.speech-bubble {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background:#6441a5;
  margin: auto;
}
.centered{
  width:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your header h4 the same width as your speech-bubble: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hxjdy720/

```
 h4 {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put your two elements in one div, like this:

```css
body {
  font-family: Europa;
}

.header {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.speech-bubble {
  height: 500px;
  width:500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background:#6441a5;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
        <h4>header</h4>

        <div class="speech-bubble">

        </div>
    </div>
```